# Get logged in user privileges of a windows client machine from a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any possibility to get the user account privileges who have logged in to a windows system from a web application?

The web application as such doesn't have any login, and we want to get the client user privileges who have logged into the system.

We want to check whether the user have got admin privileges.

Is there any possibility to get the details from user agent string or any thing like that?

Or can we do anything on the client machine to get currently logged in user privileges like executing a bat file in the client machine to get its current user privileges.

Please suggest..

Thanks,

Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

If this is an intranet application, it sounds like it has to be. I am guessing you can just configure IIS with Windows NT Challenge/Response for incoming authentication...

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windowsnt/4/server/reskit/en-us/inet/security.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: sorry , this is not an intranet application, can it have any solution if its an internet application?